# constrained linear regression / quadratic programming python

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression, quadratic-programming

I have a dataset like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.2, 2.3, 4.2])
b = np.array([1, 5, 6])
c = np.array([5.4, 6.2, 1.9])

m = np.vstack([a,b,c])
y = np.array([5.3, 0.9, 5.6])
```

and want to fit a constrained linear regression

y = b1*a + b2*b + b3*c

where all b's sum to one and are positive: b1+b2+b3=1

A similar problem in R is specified here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21565/how-do-i-fit-a-constrained-regression-in-r-so-that-coefficients-total-1

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT**:
*These two approaches are very general and can work for small-medium scale instances. For a more efficient approach, check the answer of* **chthonicdaemon** (using customized preprocessing and scipy's optimize.nnls).

### Using scipy

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

a = np.array([1.2, 2.3, 4.2])
b = np.array([1, 5, 6])
c = np.array([5.4, 6.2, 1.9])

m = np.vstack([a,b,c])
y = np.array([5.3, 0.9, 5.6])

def loss(x):
    return np.sum(np.square((np.dot(x, m) - y)))

cons = ({'type': 'eq',
         'fun' : lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.0})

x0 = np.zeros(m.shape[0])
res = minimize(loss, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons,
               bounds=[(0, np.inf) for i in range(m.shape[0])], options={'disp': True})

print(res.x)
print(np.dot(res.x, m.T))
print(np.sum(np.square(np.dot(res.x, m) - y)))
```

#### Output

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
        Current function value: 18.817792344
        Iterations: 5
        Function evaluations: 26
        Gradient evaluations: 5
[ 0.7760881  0.         0.2239119]
[ 1.87173571  2.11955951  4.61630834]
18.817792344
```

#### Evaluation

- It's obvious that the model-capabilitites / model-complexity is not enough to obtain a good performance (high loss!)

### Using general-purpose QP/SOCP-optimization modelled by cvxpy

Advantages:

- cvxpy prooves, that the problem is convex
- convergence for convex optimization problems is guaranteed (might be also true for the above)
- in general: better accuracy
- in general: more robust in regards to numerical instabilities (solver is only able to solve SOCPs; not non-convex models like the SLSQP-approach above!)

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *

a = np.array([1.2, 2.3, 4.2])
b = np.array([1, 5, 6])
c = np.array([5.4, 6.2, 1.9])

m = np.vstack([a,b,c])
y = np.array([5.3, 0.9, 5.6])

X = Variable(m.shape[0])
constraints = [X >= 0, sum_entries(X) == 1.0]

product = m.T * diag(X)
diff = sum_entries(product, axis=1) - y
problem = Problem(Minimize(norm(diff)), constraints)
problem.solve(verbose=True)

print(problem.value)
print(X.value)
```

#### Output

```
ECOS 2.0.4 - (C) embotech GmbH, Zurich Switzerland, 2012-15. Web: www.embotech.com/ECOS

It     pcost       dcost      gap   pres   dres    k/t    mu     step   sigma     IR    |   BT
 0  +0.000e+00  -0.000e+00  +2e+01  5e-01  1e-01  1e+00  4e+00    ---    ---    1  1  - |  -  - 
 1  +2.451e+00  +2.539e+00  +4e+00  1e-01  2e-02  2e-01  8e-01  0.8419  4e-02   2  2  2 |  0  0
 2  +4.301e+00  +4.306e+00  +2e-01  5e-03  7e-04  1e-02  4e-02  0.9619  1e-02   2  2  2 |  0  0
 3  +4.333e+00  +4.334e+00  +2e-02  4e-04  6e-05  1e-03  4e-03  0.9326  2e-02   2  1  2 |  0  0
 4  +4.338e+00  +4.338e+00  +5e-04  1e-05  2e-06  4e-05  1e-04  0.9698  1e-04   2  1  1 |  0  0
 5  +4.338e+00  +4.338e+00  +3e-05  8e-07  1e-07  3e-06  7e-06  0.9402  7e-03   2  1  1 |  0  0
 6  +4.338e+00  +4.338e+00  +7e-07  2e-08  2e-09  6e-08  2e-07  0.9796  1e-03   2  1  1 |  0  0
 7  +4.338e+00  +4.338e+00  +1e-07  3e-09  4e-10  1e-08  3e-08  0.8458  2e-02   2  1  1 |  0  0
 8  +4.338e+00  +4.338e+00  +7e-09  2e-10  2e-11  9e-10  2e-09  0.9839  5e-02   1  1  1 |  0  0

OPTIMAL (within feastol=1.7e-10, reltol=1.5e-09, abstol=6.5e-09).
Runtime: 0.000555 seconds.

4.337947939  # needs to be squared to be compared to scipy's output!
             #  as we are using l2-norm (outer sqrt) instead of sum-of-squares
             #  which is nicely converted to SOCP-form and easier to
             #  tackle by SOCP-based solvers like ECOS
             #  -> does not change the solution-vector x, only the obj-value
[[  7.76094262e-01]
 [  7.39698388e-10]
 [  2.23905737e-01]]
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much. I was just curious why calling the loss function in the minimize function does not require a parameter in the paranthesis? We define the loss function as loss(x), but when we call it in the minimize function, we only type in loss, instead of loss(x). Do you know why??

Comment: @sascha that was a helpful explanation! Note that I had to change, in the `cvxpy` functionality, the `sum_entries` calls to `sum` - I did *not* `import *`, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 6):

You can get a good solution to this with a little bit of math and `scipy.optimize.nnls`:

First we do the math:

If

y = b1*a + b2*b + b3*c and b1 + b2 + b3 = 1, then b3 = 1 - b1 - b2.

If we substitute and simplify we end up with

y - c = b1(a - c) + b2(b - c)

Now, we don't have any equality constraints and nnls can solve directly:

```
import scipy.optimize
A = np.vstack([a - c, b - c]).T
(b1, b2), norm = scipy.optimize.nnls(A, y - c)
b3 = 1 - b1 - b2
```

This recovers the same solution as obtained in the other answer using cvxpy.

```
b1 = 0.77608809648662802
b2 = 0.0
b3 = 0.22391190351337198
norm = 4.337947941595865
```

This approach can be generalised to an arbitrary number of dimensions as follows. Assume that we have a matrix B constructed with a, b, c from the original question arranged in the columns. Any additional dimensions will get added to this.

Now, we can do

```
A = B[:, :-1] - B[:, -1:]
bb, norm = scipy.optimize.nnls(A, y - B[:, -1])
bi = np.append(bb, 1 - sum(bb))
```

Comment: That's a nice approach!

Comment: @sascha Thanks! I'd be interested to see how nnls compares to the more general solver for a larger problem.

Comment: For a fixed number of rows, [this fairly naive benchmark](https://gist.github.com/sschnug/5d30e1787acd9e8bb69bd53368df6939) shows that your approach is super fast. But it would be interesting to make it more general to solve it for x rows. Using more rows, my SOCP-based approach is also faster than SLSQP, which dominates for 3 rows.

Comment: @sascha I've [updated the benchmark](https://gist.github.com/alchemyst/a8af6badd304d73e882ddfd4cd6cd2bd) with the generalised and the nnls solution appears much faster even with more dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

One comment regarding [sascha's scipy implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39852921/constrained-linear-regression-quadratic-programming-python#39853507): be aware that with scipy minimize, the trial-and-error nature of SLSQP may get you a solution that is *slightly* off unless you make some other specifications, namely the maximum iterations (maxiter) and maximum tolerance (ftol), as detailed in the scipy docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html#optimize-minimize-slsqp).

The default values are: maxiter=100 and ftol=1e-06.

Here is an example to illustrate using matrix notation: first get rid of the constraints and bounds.  Also assume for simplicity that the intercept=0.  In that case, the coefficients for any multiple regression, as covered [here](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~jennings/stat514/stat512notes/topic3.pdf) on page 4, will be (precisely):

```
def betas(y, x):
    # y and x are ndarrays--response & design matrixes
    return np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(x.T, x)), np.dot(x.T, y))
```

Now, given that the goal of least squares regression is to minimize the sum of squared residuals, take sascha's loss function (re-written slightly):

```
def resids(b, y, x):
    resid = y - np.dot(x, b)
    return np.dot(resid.T, resid)
```

Given your actual Y and X vectors, you can plug in the resulting "true" betas from the first equation above into the second to get a much better "benchmark."  Compare this benchmark to the .fun attribute of res (what scipy minimize spits out).  Even tiny changes can cause meaningful changes to the resulting coefficients.

So to make a long story short, it will sacrifice speed but improve accuracy to use something like

```
options={'maxiter' : 1000, 'ftol' : 1e-07}
```

within sascha's code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a linear least squares, you could solve it directly with a quadratic programming solver using the [`solve_ls`](https://scaron.info/doc/qpsolvers/least-squares.html#qpsolvers.solve_ls) function in [qpsolvers](https://github.com/stephane-caron/qpsolvers). Here is a snippet adapted from [this post on linear regression in Python](https://scaron.info/blog/simple-linear-regression-with-online-updates.html):

```py
from qpsolvers import solve_ls

# Objective (|| R x - s ||^2): || [a b c] x - y ||^2
R = m.T
s = y

# Linear constraint (A * x == b): sum(x) = 1
A = np.ones((1, 3))
b = np.array([1.0])

# Box constraint (lb <= x): x >= 0
lb = np.zeros(3)

x = solve_ls(R, s, A=A, b=b, lb=lb, solver="quadprog")
```

On my machine this code finds the solution `x = array([0.7760881, 0.0, 0.2239119])`. I've uploaded the full code to [`constrained_linear_regression.py`](https://github.com/stephane-caron/qpsolvers/blob/19db938f7b95759e6bdee729f7b5cb35e9acca2a/examples/constrained_linear_regression.py), feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @sascha for the great answer! the `cvxpy` example there is pretty out of date, so thought I would provide a slightly different version based on their [current API](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/least_squares.html) and with some light editing, for clarity:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

x1 = np.arange(1000)
x2 = np.random.normal(size=(1000,))
x = np.vstack([x1, x2]).T

y = np.random.random_sample(size=(1000,))

print("x shape", x.shape)
print("y shape", y.shape)

weights = cp.Variable(x.shape[1])

objective = cp.sum_squares(x @ weights - y)
minimize = cp.Minimize(objective)

constraints = [weights >= 0, cp.sum(weights) == 1.0]
problem = cp.Problem(minimize, constraints)

problem.solve(verbose=True)

print(problem.value)
print(weights.value)
```

I'll add that `cvxpy` is actively managed and the team there seems very responsive.